# URLDecoder in Java chokes on "São Paulo"

Tags: java, url, encoding

I'm playing a bit in Java with the `URLDecoder` class to analyze some urls, and I've hit an issue. I'm not sure if it's a bug or expected behavior, so here it is.

Consider this URL:
https://id2.s.nfl.com/fans/mobile/login?gigyresp=true&city=**S%u00e3o+Paulo%2c+Brazil**&profileURL=...

`URLDecoder` is choking on the "São Paulo" part, especially the "ã" which seems to be encoded as "%u0". Pretty much anything else seems to be handled fine, but this particular doesn't.

I'm using the following:

```
URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

My stack trace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "u0"
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:173)
```

Any thoughts how I could make `URLDecoder` parse this correctly?

Comment: If I put it into an URLEncoder online, I get `S%C3%A3o%20Paulo`

Comment: This isn't a properly URL-encoded string - percent-encoded bytes can only range from %00 to %FF. You'll have to use something other than URLDecoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL enoding is done with octets `%AB`. Your encoding seems to be a mix of java string encoding `\u00e3` and URL encoding like `%xxxx`, which is not valid.

If you change the string to `"S\u00e3o Paulo, Brazil"` and encode it with `URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")`, you will get `S%C3%A3o+Paulo%2c+Brazil`, which is perfectly decodable.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Unfortunately these URLs are not something I can control, these are referers that come in on an ad server, and need to be parsed as is. Not sure why this happens, but I'll have to find a way around it during parsing.

Comment: See also [Percent encoding - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations), which elaborates a bit on `%uxxxx` encoding.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Microsoft non-standard encoding. It is an illegal URL, everybody should reject it.

You'll need to decode it yourself: `%u####` is the unicode `####`